# in python error while importing GeoIP on CentOs server

Tags: python, django

I am using Django, and when I am using the geoip package or importing GeoIP I am getting the following error on centos, while it is working well on ubuntu 12.04.

The error is as follows

```
 from django.contrib.gis.utils.geoip import GeoIP
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/utils/geoip.py", line 67, in <module>
    'Try setting GEOIP_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.' % lib_name)
django.contrib.gis.utils.geoip.GeoIPException: Could not find the GeoIP library (tried "GeoIP"). Try setting GEOIP_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

please try to help me out, I can't go further without this.

Answer (score 1):

trying doing this on both of your systems:

```
$ echo $GEOIP_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and compare the output. From the error message, it sounds like you will get a directory path on Ubuntu, and make sure the same path is set up on CentOS, like so (on the centOS system):

```
$ export GEOIP_LIBRARY_PATH=$GEOIP_LIBRARY_PATH:<path returned from Ubuntu system>
```

Answer (score 0):

The django geoip code is using the MaxMind free geoip data that is distributed in the form of a proprietary file-based 'database'. You're probably missing the rpm package for that, after which you can locate the shared library it provides & set the GEOIP_LIBRARY_PATH to point to it. Looks like there's both [an example of setting the path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/) and [some packages for CentOS](http://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=geoip&submit=Search%20...) as well.